# How do I operate on a huge matrix (100000x100000) stored as nested list?

Tags: python, list, matrix

**Circumstances**

I have a procedure which will construct a matrix using the given list of values!
and the list starts growing bigger like 100 thousand or million values in a list, which in turn, will result in million x million size matrix.

in the procedure, i am doing some add/sub/div/multiply operations on the matrix, either based on the row, the column or just the element.

**Issues**

since the matrix is so big that i don`t think doing the whole manipulation in the memory would work.

**Questions**

therefore, my question would be: 
how should i manipulate this huge matrix and the huge value list?
like, where to store it, how to read it etc, so that i could carry out my operations on the matrix and the computer won`t stuck or anything.

Comment: That's incredibly bad idea — Python is not designed for this. Consider using for example, C++ with [STXXL](http://stxxl.sourceforge.net).

Comment: That's not going to work. Tell us about the calculations. Is the matrix dense? What does the matrix describe?

Comment: If it's numeric data, don't use Python `list`s. Use a proper numerical array type, like `numpy.array`. Further, if your data is largely zeroes, use a sparse matrix.

Comment: @David Heffernan , the matrix is dense. and it is a pairwise-comparison  for the n elements, which is a NxN matrix. as for the operations, i do sum for each row and each column and have to do a divide operation for each element in the matrix.

Comment: @Li-aung Yip, it is numeric data and not a sparse matrix. I will change to numpy.array then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, such matrix would have 10G elements. Considering that for any useful operation you would then need 30G elements, each taking 4-8 bytes, you cannot assume to do this at all on a 32-bit computer using any sort of in-memory technique. To solve this, I would use a) genuine 64-bit machine, b) memory-mapped binary files for storage, and c) ditch python.

### Update

And as I calculated below, if you have 2 input matrices and 1 output matrix, 100000 x 100000 32 bit float/integer elements, that is 120 GB (not quite GiB, though) of data. Assume, on a home computer you could achieve constant 100 MB/s I/O bandwidth, every single element of a matrix needs to be accessed for any operation including addition and subtraction, the absolute lower limit for operations would be 120 GB / (100 MB/s) = 1200 seconds, or 20 minutes, for a single matrix operation. Written in C, using the operating system as efficiently as possible, memmapped IO and so forth. For million by million elements, each operation takes 100 times as many time, that is 1.5 days. And as the hard disk is saturated during that time, the computer might just be completely unusable.

Comment: Why ditch Python?  There are plenty of ways to mmap binary data in Python, as well as libraries for working with sparse matrixes.

Comment: Ok, not ditch python for the entire problem domain, just that this that was asked should not be done in python.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan and why not, 100 GB memmapped plain data is easy for a 64 bit computer. That is how MongoDB works (for quite limited meaning of "work", but anyhow). Matrix addition, and subtraction are rowwise, matrix multiplication is more bit of a problem though.

Comment: No, I did not say. Anyhow, if you read carefully, he wants to manipulate 10G element matrices "without causing the computer to hang" etc etc, I think I sense a troll :D

Comment: You'd just have to wait an age for any answer

Comment: @Antti Haapala, a) i am on 64-bit machine. b)I will check out the mmap binary data c)python is that much weak in that? then what language do you recommend? C++?

Comment: this is such a lower level task that in the end all you would do in python would be just calling a routine that was written in C.

Comment: @Antti Haapala, SO it has to be C/C++?! okey!

Comment: the running time of matrix multiplication is O(n^3) complexity. If you are doing matrix **multiplication**, you do realize it means that multiplying 100000x100000 matrix by another takes 1000 times as much time than 10000x10000. For those sizes you really want to be as efficient as possible if you want the answer in this hour. If you do not have 120 gigabytes of ram for 3 matrices, but only say 4G then the operating system needs to read in and write out 116G I/O during a multiplication, at minimum. With 100M/s disk io, a single multiplication is going to take at least 15-20 minutes, period.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using [NumPy](https://numpy.org/). It's quite fast on arithmetic operations.

Comment: I will definitely switch to numpy! :P

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a dictionary? If the matrix is very sparse it might be feasible to store it as

```
matrix = {
 (101, 10213) : "value1",
 (1099, 78933) : "value2"
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about doing matrix multiplication/addition? Or just operations on individual elements? If matrix ... have you look at scipy.sparse?

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure is not possible with arrays, it is too large. If the matrix is for instance a binary matrix you could look at representations for its storage like hashing larger blocks of zeros together to the same bucket.